# Rails `belongs_to through` via has_one trough where the join model has_many of the child models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Imagine a travel website where you have `HotelOwner`s and `Tourist`s. When they start a conversation, the app creates a join model named `Conversation` using has_many through. It's a classic many to many association:

```
class HotelOwner
  has_many :tourists, through: :conversations
  has_many :conversations
end

class Tourist
  has_many :hotel_owners, through: :conversations
  has_many :conversations
end

class Conversation
  belongs_to :hotel_owner
  belongs_to :tourist
end
```

Now we can use `hotel_owner.tourists` and `tourist.hotel_owners`. Also, the join model `Conversation` is also being used to keep some state on that association between them both (like, `HotelOwner` comments on `Tourist` and vice-versa).

But now we need a Reservation model. My initial ideia was this:

```
class Reservation
  belongs_to :hotel_owner
  belongs_to :tourist
end
```

But we also need to create the `Conversation` join model, since app logic requires that there cannot be a `Reservation` without a previous `Conversation`, even if a blank one. Also, the hotel_owner notes on tourist and vice-versa should be kept there and need to exist if a reservation exists.

After thinking about using manual callbacks to manually create the join model `Conversation`, I read that it would not be a good idea to add a `belongs_to :conversation` on `Reservation` because it could lead to database inconsistencies (like the problem if `reservation.conversation.tourist` pointed to a different tourist then `reservation.tourist` .. there should be a single source of truth to this association right?)

I then had the idea of using `Conversation` as a proxy to Reservations, like this:

```
class HotelOwner
  has_many :tourists, through: :conversations
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :reservations, through: :conversations
end

class Tourist
  has_many :hotel_owners, through: :conversations
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :reservations, through: :conversations
end

class Conversation
  belongs_to :hotel_owner
  belongs_to :tourist
  has_many   :reservations
end

class Reservation
  has_one :hotel_owner, through: :conversation
  has_one :tourist,     through: :conversation
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

Since there is no `belongs_to through` in Rails to use in `Reservation`, other posts in SO suggest using `has_one trough` instead, just like I did above.

The problem is that conversation *has_many* reservations, and does not *belong_to* a reservation (like it does belong to a `Tourist` and `HotelOwner`).

It's not only semantics that bother me. If I do `hotel_owner.reservations.create(tourist: Tourist.last)`, it does create the Reservation, but the join model `Conversation` is not created, leaving `reservation.conversation` nil.

After a simple `hotel_owner.reload`, `hotel_owner.reservations` return nil.

What is the correct database design and Rails association model for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

you can keep it simple like this:

```
class HotelOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :conversations
end

class Tourist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end

# hotel_owner_id, tourist_id
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tourist
  belongs_to :hotel_owner

  has_one :conversation, dependent: :destroy
  after_create { self.conversation.create! }
end

# reservation_id
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

Then you can access these associations as follows:

```
# get all reservations and conversations for a hotel_owner
HotelOwner.last.reservations
HotelOwner.last.conversations

# all reservations made by a tourist
Tourist.last.reservations

# conversation associated to a reservation
Reservation.last.conversation

# get reservation, hotel_owner and tourist from a conversation
Conversation.last.reservation
Conversation.last.reservation.tourist
Conversation.last.reservation.hotel_owner
```